# Is it possible to include a generated make-style (not cmake-style) dependencies file in cmake?

Tags: dependencies, makefile, cmake, vala

I'm working with [Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/), which is compiled first to C then compiled from C as normal.

One feature of `valac` (the Vala compiler) is to generate a "fast-vapi" for a `.vala` file. A fast-vapi is essentially a generated header file for the `.vala` file. The point of fast-vapis is that they allow incremental builds.

So, a simplified sequence of commands to build a project looks something like this:

```
valac --fast-vapi=source1.vapi source1.vala # generate source1.vapi
valac --fast-vapi=source2.vapi source2.vala # generate source2.vapi
valac -C --use-fast-vapi=source2.vapi source1.vapi # generate source1.c
valac -C --use-fast-vapi=source1.vapi source2.vapi # generate source2.c
```

When writing the cmake dependencies of `source1.c`, one approach is for it to depend on every fast-vapi but its own. This quickly becomes cumbersome for large projects, as often changes to other .vapis do not effect `source1.vala`. So `valac` supports the `--deps` flag:

```
valac -C --deps=source1.dep --use-fast-vapi=source2.vapi source1.vapi
```

This generates make-style dependencies for `source1.dep` in `source1.dep`. For example:

```
source1.dep: source2.vapi source5.vapi ...
```

If I was writing a plain `Makefile`, I could simply do `include source1.dep`. However, I can't find any similar construct for `cmake`.

How can I include a generated make-style dependencies file in `cmake`?

Comment: Since your generated dependencies are in make-style, maybe [this link](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-October/039995.html) helps?

Answer (score 1):

The Vala compiler will not write new C files if they haven't changed. If your program is made of multiple source files and you recompile, the Vala compiler will only update the C and header files that have changed and then your C compiler's dependency process can pick up the rest.

The Vala compiler itself, which uses make and autotools, doesn't provide any information about the dependencies between the Vala compiler and the build system. The Vala compiler gets called and produces the C files, and then autotool's method for determining dependencies of C files takes over. There's not reason that logic could not be used in CMake.

Comment: @apamasell: I'm talking about a fast-vapi-based build system, not the traditional "generate all C files in one step" process. The dependencies that I'm talking about are between generated .c/.dep files and fast-vapis, not between .o files and .h files. See https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Documentation/ParallelBuilds. I gave a detailed explanation in my original post.

Comment: I think you'd have to parse the dep files and and add_dependencies in your CMake file.